# SQL query to count different values within a particular duration in timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have got a datastream in MySQL which looks like the example below. Any idea to count situations where I have data within a 15 second duration where I am into at least three speed zones like:

- from WALK to RUN or
- from RUN to SPRINT or
- from JOG to HIGH_SPEED_RUN

only in acceleration, order is: WALK, JOG, RUN, HIGH_SPEED_RUN, SPRINT

```
timestamp               speed
2022-01-12 14:47:43.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:48:08.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:49:07.000 JOG
2022-01-12 14:49:47.000 JOG
2022-01-12 14:49:52.000 JOG
2022-01-12 14:49:57.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:50:02.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:50:07.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:50:12.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:50:17.000 WALK
2022-01-12 14:50:27.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:13.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:18.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:23.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:28.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:33.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:38.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:43.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:48.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:53.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:15:58.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:03.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:08.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:18.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:23.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:28.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:33.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:38.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:16:42.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:23:00.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:23:05.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:23:10.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:23:20.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:23:25.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:23:35.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:47:12.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:47:17.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:47:21.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:47:26.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:48:26.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:49:47.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:49:52.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:49:57.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:50:02.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:50:07.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:50:12.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:50:17.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:50:32.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:51:12.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:51:22.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:51:27.000 WALK **from**
2022-01-12 15:51:37.000 RUN **to**
2022-01-12 15:51:42.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:51:47.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:51:52.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:51:57.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:02.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:06.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:11.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:16.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:21.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:31.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:41.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:46.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:51.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:52:56.000 RUN
2022-01-12 15:53:01.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:53:06.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:53:11.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:53:16.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:53:36.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:53:41.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:53:56.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:54:11.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:54:16.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:54:41.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:54:46.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:55:00.000 JOG
2022-01-12 15:55:05.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:55:45.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:55:50.000 WALK
2022-01-12 15:59:14.000 RUN **from**
2022-01-12 15:59:19.000 SPRINT
2022-01-12 15:59:24.000 SPRINT
2022-01-12 15:59:29.000 SPRINT **to**
2022-01-12 15:59:34.000 SPRINT
2022-01-12 15:59:39.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 15:59:44.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 15:59:49.000 RUN
2022-01-12 15:59:54.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 16:02:43.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:02:48.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:02:58.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:03.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:07.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:17.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:22.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:27.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:32.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:37.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:42.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:03:47.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:03:52.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:03:57.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:02.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:07.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:12.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:17.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:22.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:27.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:32.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:37.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:42.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:04:47.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:52.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:04:57.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:06:51.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:06:56.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:07:01.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:07:06.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:07:11.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:07:16.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:07:21.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:07:56.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:08:01.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:08:06.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:08:11.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:08:16.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:08:21.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:08:26.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:08:45.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:09:00.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:18:52.000 JOG **from**
2022-01-12 16:18:57.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN **to**
2022-01-12 16:19:02.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:19:41.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 16:19:51.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:20:01.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:21:01.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:25:19.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:26:14.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:26:24.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:27:09.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:31:52.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:31:57.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:33:41.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:33:46.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:35:06.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:36:06.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:36:11.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:37:20.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:37:45.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:38:30.000 JOG **from**
2022-01-12 16:38:40.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN **to**
2022-01-12 16:38:50.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:38:55.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:38:59.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:39:09.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:40:04.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:40:49.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:41:53.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:42:58.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:43:03.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:43:08.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:43:13.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:43:23.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:43:33.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:44:18.000 SPRINT
2022-01-12 16:44:23.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 16:44:32.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:44:37.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:45:07.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:45:12.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:45:17.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:45:37.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:45:42.000 RUN **from**
2022-01-12 16:45:47.000 SPRINT
2022-01-12 16:45:52.000 SPRINT **to**
2022-01-12 16:45:57.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:46:12.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:46:42.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:46:52.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:46:57.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:47:02.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:47:26.000 WALK **from**
2022-01-12 16:47:31.000 RUN **to**
2022-01-12 16:47:41.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:48:11.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:48:16.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:48:51.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:48:56.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:52:10.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:53:04.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:53:09.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:53:19.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:54:24.000 WALK **from**
2022-01-12 16:54:39.000 RUN **to**
2022-01-12 16:54:49.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:54:54.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:54:59.000 JOG
2022-01-12 16:56:53.000 RUN
2022-01-12 16:57:13.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:58:32.000 WALK
2022-01-12 16:58:57.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:04:30.000 RUN
2022-01-12 17:04:35.000 RUN
2022-01-12 17:05:20.000 JOG **from**
2022-01-12 17:05:30.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN **to**
2022-01-12 17:05:35.000 WALK **from**
2022-01-12 17:05:50.000 RUN
2022-01-12 17:05:55.000 SPRINT **to**
2022-01-12 17:06:05.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 17:06:15.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:06:40.000 WALK **from**
2022-01-12 17:06:49.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:06:54.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN **to**
2022-01-12 17:06:59.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN
2022-01-12 17:07:39.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:07:44.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:07:49.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:07:54.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:07:59.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:08:04.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:08:14.000 JOG **from**
2022-01-12 17:08:29.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN **to**
2022-01-12 17:08:44.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:08:49.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:09:24.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:09:43.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:10:58.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:11:28.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:11:53.000 WALK **from**
2022-01-12 17:12:03.000 RUN
2022-01-12 17:12:08.000 RUN **to**
2022-01-12 17:12:17.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:12:52.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:13:32.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:13:52.000 RUN
2022-01-12 17:13:57.000 JOG **from**
2022-01-12 17:14:07.000 HIGH_SPEED_RUN **to**
2022-01-12 17:14:12.000 JOG
2022-01-12 17:18:10.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:26:52.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:27:07.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:27:32.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:27:37.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:27:52.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:28:17.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:28:22.000 WALK
2022-01-12 17:28:51.000 WALK
```

Comment: Just to be clear you don't want deceleration?

Comment: Post expected result for the data.

Comment: Just acceleration. Result should just an integer.

Comment: If i count manually right, the result should be 14 in this example.

Comment: Are you using MySQL8 or newer?

Comment: Sorry to be not specific. I'm using mariadb.  mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB

Comment: I updated the code part and seperated the expected sets by blank line and *. At the end i just expect the Value: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to merge consecutive rows having same speed together. In the resulting data, compare each row with next row to see (i) if next speed is two steps faster (ii) the difference is less than 15 seconds.

Here is the query ([seems to return 11 rows for the sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e04cdfc9b645c20eaf4fde2808c8b17)):

```
with cte1 as (
    select *, field(speed, 'walk', 'jog', 'run', 'high_speed_run', 'sprint') as speed_num
    from t
), cte2 as (
    select *, case when speed_num = lag(speed_num) over (order by timestamp) then 0 else 1 end as new_group
    from cte1
), cte3 as (
    select *, sum(new_group) over (order by timestamp) as group_num
    from cte2
), cte4 as (
    select min(timestamp) as start_time, max(timestamp) as end_time, any_value(speed_num) as speed_num
    from cte3
    group by group_num
), cte5 as (
    select *, lead(speed_num) over (order by start_time) as next_speed, lead(start_time) over (order by start_time) as next_time
    from cte4
)
select *
from cte5
where next_speed > speed_num + 1
and next_time < end_time + interval 15 second
order by 1
```

Comment: Well, quicktipp if function any_value is not existend...